# UserCake Migration - Admin Account/Password Does Not Log In

Tags: php, mysql, usercake

I was testing the UserCake installation on my own site and am now moving it to a client site. In migrating the files and database, I'm having an issue logging into my admin account. If I type a non-existent account, it gives an error message indicating incorrect login (as expected). If I log in with the admin username and password, it simply goes back to the login page with no error message displayed.

EDIT: It seems Sessions aren't being saved.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that php.ini was not configured to save sessions in a directory that the user had access to. Setting it to a directory they could access fixed the problem.